Computing a surface integral
I have to verify that the line integral and the surface integral of Stokes' Theorem are equal for the vector field $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{F}}(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ and the portion of the surface $S$ defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, $3x+2y-z\geq 1$. But I need to show a parametrization of that surface too.
Using the hint given here, I parameterize the region with spherical coordinates:
$$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}(u,v)=(3\sin v\,\cos u, 3\sin v\, \sin u, 3\cos v)$$
where $0\leq u \leq 2\pi$. I'm stuck when it comes to using the constraint $3x+2y-z\geq 1$ to solve $v$ as a function of $u$, because I'm getting
$$9\sin v\, \cos u+ 6 \sin v\,\sin u - 3\cos v=1$$
I don't know how to solve this equation, and now I'm wondering if this is the best way to go about it.

For starters, your parametrization will not give the usual orientation of the sphere. Note that $\partial\mathbf x/\partial u\times\partial\mathbf x/\partial v$ points inward. You can actually do this problem with no surface integration at all: Note that $\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf n = 3$ and you can find the surface area by knowing that the area of a zone of a sphere is $2\pi rh$, where $r$ is the radius and $h$ is the height. Are you sure you are meant to calculate the integral explicitly? You say "I have been asked." Give the precise context, please. You might rotate the problem, for example.

But ... if you insist on doing the problem as it stands ... do the standard trigonometry trick of changing phase. Write $3\cos u + 2\sin u = \sqrt{13}\left(\frac3{\sqrt{13}}\cos u + \frac2{\sqrt{13}}\sin u\right)$ and then use the formula for $\sin(u+c)$.

@TedShifrin I have to solve the integral both ways and compare the results. But I have not been able to find a parametrization for the surface given above. I don't know the trick of changing phase. I also don't understand how you got $\sqrt{13}$ nor how it helps to get the expression $\sin(u+c)$. But I would appreciate if you can recommend me some book that can help me about it.

@TedShifrin You also mention the possibility of rotating the problem, but I have never done it before. Could you give me some suggestion about it?

What do you mean "both ways"? Please edit your post to include the exact problem as it was phrased. Since $\mathbf F$ points radially outward, you can rotate the sphere to make the plane $z=a$ for some constant $a$. (Find the distance from the origin to the given plane.) As it stands, this question is rather barbaric; the trigonometry I'm suggesting is in your precalculus book, not particularly in a calculus book, although this trick is used in physics all the time. Note that I need to divide by $\sqrt{13}$ so that I can have $3/\sqrt{13}=\sin c$ and $2/\sqrt{13}=\cos c$ for some angle $c$.

You have to do it both ways to check Stokes's Theorem, right?  Once integrating the curl of $ \mathbf F $ through the surface, and once integrating $ \mathbf F $ itself along the boundary of the surface.  But that doesn't say anything about how you do the integral of $ \nabla \times \mathbf F $ through the surface, so you can still do tricks like the one that @TedShifrin is suggesting in the first comment.

That said, I think that @TedShifrin has the wrong trick, because that uses $ \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n $, whereas you need $ \nabla \times \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n $ if you're verifying Stokes's Theorem.  But that's even easier, because $ \nabla \times \mathbf F $ is extremely simple!  If you calculate this curl first, you'll see that the surface integral is trivial.  So unless you've been explicitly instructed to give a parametrization of the surface, you can just focus on the boundary curve.

@TobyBartels The parametrization is what got me stuck. I have to show it explicitly.

In that case, then I agree with @TedShifrin that you'll need to use the sum-angle formula from trigonometry.  I can write an answer about how to do this, also perhaps Ted wants to write it, since it wasn't my idea first.

Now that it's been edited ... The force is clearly conservative, so there's nothing to check. We know that the line integral is $0$ and the flux of $\text{curl}(\mathbf F) = \mathbf 0$ is likewise $0$. There's no way a calculus problem would expect you to parametrize this surface in spherical coordinates. If we had an interesting line integral to do, the right thing to do would be to parametrize the circle by using a different coordinate system. Anyhow, @Toby, I have no desire to grind this out, so feel free to steal :)

@Toby In my own defense, before the post was edited (at my request), we didn't know it was the flux of the curl that was required. :P

@TedShifrin :  Yes, I eventually figured that out.

You need to solve the equation $ 9 \sin v \cos u + 6 \sin v \sin u - 3 \cos v = 1 $ for $ u $ or $ v $.  Since $ u $ appears less often, let's solve it for $ u $.
Focussing on the terms with $ u $, you can factor $ 9 \sin v \cos u + 6 \sin v \sin u $ as $ 3 \sin v \, ( 3 \cos u + 2 \sin u ) $.  Because $ \sqrt { 3 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 2 } = \sqrt { 1 3 } $, you factor out $ \sqrt { 1 3 } $ as well, getting $ 3 \sqrt { 1 3 } \sin v \, ( \tfrac 3 { \sqrt { 1 3 } } \cos u + \tfrac 2 { \sqrt { 1 3 } } \sin u ) $.  You then let $ \alpha $ (which @TedShifrin called $ c $) be $ \arctan \tfrac 3 2 \approx 0 .9 8 3 $, so that $ \sin \alpha = \tfrac 3 { \sqrt { 1 3 } } $ and $ \cos \alpha = \tfrac 2 { \sqrt { 1 3 } } $.  Now you have $ 3 \sqrt { 1 3 } \sin v \sin { ( u + \alpha ) } $.
So the equation to solve has become $ 3 \sqrt { 1 3 } \sin v \sin { ( u + \alpha ) } - 3 \cos v = 1 $.  Since $ u $ only appears in here once, it's straightforward to get $$ u = \arcsin \frac { 1 + 3 \cos v } { 3 \sqrt { 1 3 } \sin v } - \alpha $$ and $$ u = \pi - \arcsin \frac { 1 + 3 \cos v } { 3 \sqrt { 1 3 } \sin v } - \alpha $$ as solutions.  Of course, there are infinitely more solutions, but they all differ from these by $ 2 \pi $.  You said that $ 0 \leq u \leq 2 \pi $, while these solutions satisfy $ - \tfrac { 3 \pi } 2 \leq u + \alpha \leq \tfrac \pi 2 $ instead; but that's fine, you can always use $ - \tfrac { 3 \pi } 2 - \alpha \leq u \leq \tfrac \pi 2 - \alpha $ if you want.
So you have the bounds on $ u $ (notice that the first solution is always less than the second one).  To get the bounds on $ v $, set these two solutions equal.  Solve for the arcsine and take the sine of both sides, and clear fractions to get $$ 3 \sqrt { 1 3 } \sin v - 3 \cos v = 1 \text . $$  Now you do the same trick; since $ \sqrt { ( 3 \sqrt { 1 3 } ) ^ 2 + ( - 3 ) ^ 2 } = 3 \sqrt { 1 4 } $, you factor the left-hand side as $ 3 \sqrt { 1 4 } ( \tfrac { \sqrt { 1 3 } } { \sqrt { 1 4 } } \sin v - \tfrac 1 { \sqrt { 1 4 } } \cos v ) $ and let $ \beta $ be $ \arctan ( - \tfrac 1 { \sqrt { 1 3 } } ) \approx - 0 .2 7 1 $ so that you can write this as $ 3 \sqrt { 1 4 } \sin ( v + \beta ) $.  Now you can solve for $ v $, again taking two solutions, the two with $ - \tfrac { 3 \pi } 2 - \beta \leq v \leq \tfrac \pi 2 - \beta $ being the most convenient (and also the two satisfying $ 0 \leq v \leq \pi $, which you really shouldn't mess with).
I'd hate to integrate anything between those bounds on $ u $, and even the bounds on $ v $ aren't pretty, but fortunately you only have to integrate $ \nabla \times \mathbf F \cdot đ \mathbf S = 0 $, so it's not that bad.

Thank you for taking the time to write an answer using the sum-angle formula. This is very useful for me as it is a trick I don't often use.

You're welcome!  I agree with Ted that it's kind of unreasonable to expect you to work this all out in a Calculus course, but it can be a handy thing to know how to do.
